# preg_* functions matching subpattern with quantifier

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex of this form:

```
/(?:^- (.*)$\r*\n*)+/m
```

The intention is to match one or more lines of text that start with `-[space]`.

This works fine, except for when it comes to collecting the matched subpatterns `(.*)`. Only the last one is returned, and any previous subpattern matches (which appear in the result array as part of index 0) are lost.

I really need some way of getting those subpatterns in an array, so I can pass them to `implode` and do what I'm trying to do with them.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Could you show us some examples of input string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use

```
preg_match_all('/^- (.*)\r\n/m', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($result);
```

For example:

```
<?php
$subject = "- some line
- some content
- some other content
nothing to match over here
- more things here
- more patterns
nothing to match here
";

preg_match_all('/^- (.*)\r\n/m', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Outcome:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "- some line
"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "- some content
"
    [2]=>
    string(21) "- some other content
"
    [3]=>
    string(19) "- more things here
"
    [4]=>
    string(16) "- more patterns
"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "some line"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "some content"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "some other content"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "more things here"
    [4]=>
    string(13) "more patterns"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good place to start, but then how would I effect a `preg_replace` on that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. To build a regex pattern from the initial `$subject` var, I would do `$someVar = '/'.implode('|', $result[1]).'/';` then use `$someOtherVar = preg_replace($someVar, $someReplacement, $textVar);` (I edited the regex a little bit, to leave out the `\r\n`). I apologize if I misunderstood.